# JSP equivalent of <cfimage action="writetobrowser">

Tags: jsp, coldfusion

I have worked in ColdFusion and found a tag called [`<cfimage>`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7945.html). One feature of this tag is it allows you to write an image directly to the browser by using the action attribute like so:

```
<cfimage action="writetobrowser" source="#someImage#">
```

Is there a tag, or some other method, in jsp that supports this?

I am new in JSP thing so maybe I am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

It can be easily done by `HTML <img>` Tag.

Let say you have images folder at webapps.
 `<img src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/images/Bee2.jpg" height="330" width="300"/>`

Comment: I noticed one thing when we use 'writetobrowser' in cfm it does not allow user to save or open that image file in new tab or so by using menu by 'right clicking' on the respective image.May be I am wrong but I noticed it......
please rectify me if I am wrong.............

Comment: cfimage action="writetobrowser" does more than a simple html img tag.  It allows you to write an image stored in memory to the browser.  it writes out the image to a temporary location and then creates an img tag to display it.  i don't know the JSP equivalent but the html img tag is not it

Comment: True, it is not equivalent. However the image `source` can also be a url or file on disk. So it is possible the `<img>` tag would suffice if they were only working with existing images. @ankur20us - can you clarify?